# VB Array Error Grade Book Assignment

Tags: arrays, vb.net

My problem is when I input scores for four tests: 1 2 3 3, it calculates total and average everything is working great, but if I put scores for tests bigger than 3, which is bigger than my array it gives me error  in this function

```
Public Function TotalScore(studentScore() As Integer, intTotalScore As Integer) As Integer
    For Each i As Integer In studentScore
        intTotalScore += studentScore(i)
    Next
    Return intTotalScore
End Function
```

the error message is that `index is out of range array`. 
I am sorry I don't know how to explain it better if you need additional code or some more details I will be more than happy to provide. Thank you for your time

```
 Public g_intTotalScore As Integer                                                       'total score
 Public g_decAverageScore As Decimal                                                     'average score
 Public g_strLetterScore As String
 Public Const intMAX_SUBSCRIPT_STUDENTS_NAMES As Integer = 4                            'max subscript for students names 
 Public Const intMAX_SUBSCRIPT_SCORE As Integer = 3                                      'max subscript for student numeric scores on 4 test

Public strStudentsNames(intMAX_SUBSCRIPT_STUDENTS_NAMES) As String                 'array that holds students names
Public strLetterGrades() As String = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "F"}                     'array that hold letter grades
Public intStudent1(intMAX_SUBSCRIPT_SCORE) As Integer                              'hold test scores for student1
```

I create function that accepts two parameters to calculate total score of 4 tests

```
Public Function TotalScore(studentScore() As Integer, intTotalScore As Integer) As Integer
    For Each i As Integer In studentScore
        intTotalScore += studentScore(i)
    Next
    Return intTotalScore
End Function
```

Here is input for Student Name and than 4 test scores

```
Do While intCount < strStudentsNames.Length
    'input data for student number1
    If intCount = 0 Then
        intCounter = 0
        strStudentsNames(intCount) = InputBox("Enter Student Name number" &       intCount + 1, "Enter Data")
        Do While intCounter < intStudent1.Length
            intStudent1(intCounter) = CInt(InputBox("Student Name: " & strStudentsNames(intCount) & vbCrLf &
                                                    "Enter Score for test number " & intCounter + 1, "Enter Data"))
            intCounter += 1
        Loop
    End If
    intCount += 1
Loop
```

here is display data to list

```
'student1: calculate total , avaerage score, display average score, reset total score
g_intTotalScore = TotalScore(intStudent1, g_intTotalScore)
g_decAverageScore = Average(g_decAverageScore)
lstOutPut.Items.Add("Student Name: " & strStudentsNames(0) & " => The average score is: " & g_decAverageScore.ToString & " => Grade: ")
g_intTotalScore = 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error means that you are trying to get something from the array index that doesn't exists in the array. For example the array has 10 elements from 0 - 9 index and your calling the index number 11.

Try to use the for each like this:

```
For Each i As Integer In studentScore
        intTotalScore += i
Next
```